# What happened to the "Read the FAQ" banner?

Tags: discussion

Maybe this belongs on MSO, as it may be site wide. It appears the banner that prompts new visitors to read the FAQ is no longer being shown. This is just slightly embarrassing because I've been telling people not to ignore it. It was certainly here the last time I visited SF without being logged on.

[image: Server Fault's front page as a brand new visitor]

I'm not sure whether to request it to be re-enabled because there's precious little evidence anyone ever paid any attention to it.

Comment: +1 - can faithfully reproduce here; my guess is because the notification bar is now gone in preference to the supercollidermultidropdown box (which is great for registered users, not so much for anonymous users)

Comment: +1 for "supercollidermultidropdown"

Comment: I guess the announcement for this was lost amongst all those other announcements we get when they make changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this was part of the Welcome Banner then it was [diked out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85407/could-the-intro-banner-not-be-displayed-if-already-displayed-in-one-tab/122428#122428) some time ago due to low usage.

Comment: Pity in a way. Low usage or not, at least we had more of an argument in telling people to read the FAQ. It's one thing to not do it. It's something else altogether for people to blatantly ignore a big banner telling them to do so.

Comment: I can't find the reference now but my understanding is that the team want to discourage slapping people in the face with the faq.

Comment: And we, or at least some of us, want to do the opposite. I'd hate to see SF get as pathetically sloppy as SO is.

Comment: From a recent blog post. `Tired of seeing crappy questions? Close them. Irritated by lousy answers? Down-vote them. Depressed by the meaningless junk that some people post whenever they see an empty text field? Delete it! Embarrassed by poor grammar or formatting? Edit it! See someone being rude? Flag it!`

Comment: Base on that it would appear that we may as well not have an FAQ and all the effort that went into editing it was for nothing.